# Flexbox - can't keep divs in content area from overlapping footer

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a web page using a column flexbox, with fixed size header and footer, and a content area which takes up the remaining space. This works fine.

The content area is a row flexbox, and I have 2 square divs side by side. I am making them square by using padding-bottom. This works fine, unless the window is >2x the content area height. Then my squares start bleeding into the footer, because padding is based on element width.

I would like the squares to never overlap the footer. I'm ok with there just being dead space to the right of the squares. I would like to stick with flexbox and avoid floats if possible. Only modern browsers need be supported.

Is this possible with only CSS? Or is this a job for JS.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqymbt4x/2/)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#box {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid tomato;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
}
#header {
    flex: 0 0 5em;
}
#footer {
    flex: 0 0 5em;
}
#content {
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    min-height: 30%;
}
#content > div {
    background: tomato;
    border-color: black;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    max-height: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}

<div id="box">
<div id="header">
    <p><b>header</b>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id='am'></div>
    <div id='pm'></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p><b>footer</b>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

TIA!

Comment: please add code or fiddle

Comment: Make sure the footer is not positioned as absolute or fixed. If possible, set the footer to `position: relative;`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple soluton:

```
#box
{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    min-height: 100%; /* this*/
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mqymbt4x/3/)

Note: This assumes you want the page to overflow...but I didn't see any reference to containing the page height to the viewport.

Comment: I definitely would like to contain the page height to the viewport ... in particular, I would not want increasing viewport size to result in fewer items (eg the footer) being visible.

Comment: Hmmm...then I suspect what you want is not possible. The 'square' thing is what's going to break the layout. Is that an absolute requirement?

Comment: Thinking ... I suppose it would be ok if on stretching, the content area were divided into 2 equal (landscape-y, non-square) sections, each of which held a square. So the user still sees two squares, just with some space in between.

Context would probably help :) This is for a dashboard. So the page needs to fit in the viewport, and growing the browser can either grow widgets, or move widgets, but should never shrink or hide widgets. Make sense?